# Creating new object with has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

My rails project consists of three models: User, Groups and Transactions. Groups and Transactions are connected by a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship and both belong to User. I'm trying to implement a feature where you can add new transactions on a groups' show page that will automatically be associated with the show pages' group. I've tried the following but in the transactions controller rails doesn't get which group the transaction is supposed to be associated with. 
Groups' show page:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @group.name %>
  <% @group.deals.each do |deal| %>
    <%= deal.name %>
    <%= deal.user.name %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', deal %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(@group) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', groups_path %>
<%= link_to 'New Transaction', new_transaction_path(@group) %> |
```

Group's controller page:

```
  # GET /transactions/new
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

  # POST /transactions or /transactions.json
  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.save
        format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: "Transaction was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @transaction }
        @transaction.groups << @group
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If I replace @group with f.e. Group.first the association is created - it's the wrong one in most cases ofc tho. Does the solution lie within in the views maybe, can anyone help out?

Comment: Are you setting `@group = ...` somewhere? if you get the group_id from the params then you need to do `@group = Group.find(params[:group_id]` or something like that at some point before using that variable.

Comment: Your idea sounds great, but how would I go about this? Is this line in my groups show page going in the right direction?
<%= link_to 'New Transaction', new_transaction_path(@group) %> |
Can I 'send' the params like that?

Comment: I'd suggest you check the guides on nested resources https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources that's what you seem to need and it has more clear examples than what I can add as a comment